# Is there an easier way to git pull master, git rebase, git merge into master from feature branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-workflow

During development, I check out a feature branch, do my work and then follow a process that I am sure can be cleaned. It boils down to something like this:

```
git checkout -b feature-one
git add . 
git commit -m "Feature all done"
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout feature-one
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge feature-one
git push origin master
git branch -d feature-one
```

Is there a way to do all of this in fewer commands?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a script? Though you really shouldn't create a branch when you **finish** a feature - you should create it when starting on a feature. That way you can save your work-in-progress and also easily switch back to master to fix a bug if your feature isn't ready

Comment: Apologies if I wasnt clear. between steps 1 and 2 development is done.

Answer (score 1):

Sure... you could skip using your local master as your upstream and use the remote master instead... then you would do:

```
git checkout -b feature-one
git add .
git commit -m "Feature 1 complete"
git pull -r # pulling with rebase
git push # no need to specify remote branch.. it will push against the upstream branch
```

That, if the upstream branch is already set up.... that can be easily done in either of two ways:

```
git checkout -b feature-one origin/master # when the branch is created
git branch --set-upstream origin/master # with feature-one already checked out
```

Comment: I will give this a shot.